# shell script to find 5 latest .jar files, present them to user, take input and copy using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to create a shell script that does the following tasks:

1. Connect to Linux Box B from Linux Box A
2. Get list of latest 5 prop.jar files
3. Present this list to the user with serial numbers 1 to 5 and ask for user input
4. User can key in any number from 1 to 5. For any other number, an error should be displayed
5. Once user key in a proper number, this jar file should get copied from B to A

As I'm new to shell script, I'm going a bit slow. What I learned is:

- To connect to box B from box A, I'll be using ssh
- I ran a command from my shell script: *ssh user@host find  -name 'prop*.jar'* This command gave me list of desired files
- But, when I tried the command:

> ssh user@host find  -name 'prop*.jar'  -printf '%C@
>   %p\n' | sort -rn | head -n 5

I get the error- **find: paths must precede expression: %pn**

Where am I going wrong. I googled and tried many variations but the shell script still throws this error. I won't ask answer to rest of the steps as I haven't yet tried them. But surely, this step has consumed me.

**EDIT:**
I just figured out how can I copy from remote box B to box A:

- *scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [[user@]from-host:]source-file [[user@]to-host:][destination-file]*

But the original problem still remains.... Any help out there :(

Comment: Quote the entire command you're sending through ssh.

Comment: @Wrikken I've just put the command in block quotes to highlight it. This is the entire command I'm using, with proper user and hostname. It first asks me the password. After I key in the password, it throws the mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, and I still see no quotes around the command you want ssh to perform (`ssh user@host "find -name 'prop*.jar' -printf '%C@ %p\n' | sort -rn | head -n 5"`). Note that _your_ command line interprets  quotes, pipes, etc (so any quotes in for instance `-printf '%C@ %p\n'` are _lost_, and your `sort` & `head` are currently happening on your box, not on the box you're connecting to), so you need to tell it not to do that.

Comment: @Wrikken Thank you Wrikken. It worked!!!! the only confusion now is that why did it work without quotes when I was using the command till prop*.jar

Comment: It worked thusly:  `prop*.jar` is _not_ a problem, unless you have a local file in your cwd that matches it (take for instance `property.jar` locally), in which case not `prop*.jar` was sent to the server, but substituted with the local filename(s). The actual problem here is `-printf <format>`. In case of `-print '%C@ %p\n'`, the whole `'%C@ %p\n'` is the value for that option and works. However, because your _local_ command line interprets it, `-printf '%C@ %p\n'` becomes `-printf %C@ %p\n` (without the `'`), so `find` interprets `%C@` as the format, and `%p\n` as path on a wrong location.

Comment: @Wrikken Wow!!!! thanks for the great explanation Wrikken. It's really helpful. Now I can move ahead and try out the other steps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The "find" approach could have worked; it's just that the command line usage was wrong -- it's missing the directory paths before the first predicate arg "-name".

You had:

```
find -name 'prop*.jar' -printf '%C@ %p\n'
```

You needed:

```
find . -name 'prop*.jar' -printf '%C@ %p\n'
```

As others noted in the comments, you'll still likely need to double escape everything.